# Qt checkers getting weird output

Tags: c++, qt

I have gone over it many times, I am getting an extra checker when I am moving (-1, -1). on the white checker down left.

Don't mind the moving over another checker, its for the next step.

I can't find where i am setting an extra checker on the board[][]

So please if you can in anyone help, it would be much appreciated.

[Beginning of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB2PC.png)

[After moving -1 -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZh0U.png)

```
    /**
* \file CheckerWindow.cpp
* \brief Checker window
*/
#include "checkerwindow.h"
#include "ui_checkerwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>
/*!
  *Game2
  *\brief Checker
  */
CheckerWindow::CheckerWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CheckerWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(500,650);
    this->setWindowTitle("4x4 Checker");
    // board slots
    // row1
    slot[0] = QRect(50,100,100,100);
    slot[1] = QRect(150,100,100,100);
    slot[2] = QRect(250,100,100,100);
    slot[3] = QRect(350,100,100,100);
    // row2
    slot[4] = QRect(50,200,100,100);
    slot[5] = QRect(150,200,100,100);
    slot[6] = QRect(250,200,100,100);
    slot[7] = QRect(350,200,100,100);
    // row3
    slot[8] = QRect(50,300,100,100);
    slot[9] = QRect(150,300,100,100);
    slot[10] = QRect(250,300,100,100);
    slot[11] = QRect(350,300,100,100);
    // row4
    slot[12] = QRect(50,400,100,100);
    slot[13] = QRect(150,400,100,100);
    slot[14] = QRect(250,400,100,100);
    slot[15] = QRect(350,400,100,100);
    indexMoving=0;
    isMoving=false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            color[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    board[0][0]=1;
    board[0][2]=1;
    board[3][1]=2;
    board[3][3]=2;
}
CheckerWindow::~CheckerWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void CheckerWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e) {
    QPainter* painter = new QPainter(this);
    painter->fillRect(this->rect(),QColor("white"));
    painter->setPen(QColor("black"));
    int s=0;
    painter->drawRects(slot, 16);
    //to draw the background
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int slotN = i*4 + j;
            if (s == 1) {
                painter->drawPixmap(slot[slotN].x(), slot[slotN].y(), QPixmap("../Images/wood1.png") );
                s=0;
            } else{
                painter->drawPixmap(slot[slotN].x(), slot[slotN].y(), QPixmap("../Images/wood2.png") );
                s=1;
            }
        }
        s=1;
        if(i==1) {
            s=0;
        }
    }
    s=0;
    //add the chekers on the board
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int slotN = i*4 + j;
            if(color[i][j] == 1) {
                qDebug("coloring");
                painter->drawPixmap(slot[slotN].x(), slot[slotN].y(), QPixmap("../Images/green.jpeg") );
                color[i][j]=0;
                isMoving=true;
            }
            if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                painter->drawPixmap(slot[slotN].x(), slot[slotN].y(), QPixmap("../Images/checker1.png") );
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == 2){
                painter->drawPixmap(slot[slotN].x(), slot[slotN].y(), QPixmap("../Images/checker2.png") );
            }
        }
    }
}
/**
* \brief This mouseEvent() function
* will move the ball downwards by 1, at the same time it should check
* \param The MouseEvent is used to know where the mouse is pressed
*/
void CheckerWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (slot[i].contains(e->pos())) {
            qDebug("Inside e->pos");
            int row = i/4;
            int col = i%4;
            if(board[row][col]==1 || board[row][col]==2) {
                indexMoving=i;
                color[row][col]=1;
                isMoving=true;
                repaint();
                qDebug("color");
            }
            else if(isMoving) {
                qDebug("move");
                int rowOld = indexMoving/4;
                int colOld = indexMoving%4;
                if(board[rowOld][colOld]==1) {
                    if((row == rowOld+1) && (col == colOld+1) ) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 +1");
                        board[row][col]=1;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        color[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if((row == rowOld+1) && (col == colOld-1) ) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 -1");
                        board[row][col]=1;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        color[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if(board[rowOld+1][colOld+1]==2) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 +1 moving over another");
                        board[row][col]=1;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        board[rowOld+1][colOld+1]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld+1][colOld+1]=0;
                    }
                    else if(board[rowOld+1][colOld-1]==2) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 -1 moving over another");
                        board[row][col]=1;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        board[rowOld+1][colOld-1]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld+1][colOld-1]=0;
                    }
                }
                else if(board[rowOld][colOld]==2) {
                    if((row == rowOld-1) && (col == colOld-1) ) {
                        qDebug("IN -1 -1");
                        board[row][col]=2;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        color[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if((row == rowOld-1) && (col == colOld+1) ) {
                        qDebug("IN -1 +1");
                        board[row][col]=2;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        color[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if(board[rowOld-1][colOld-1]==1) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 +1 moving over another");
                        board[row][col]=2;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        board[rowOld-1][colOld-1]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld-1][colOld-1]=0;
                    }
                    else if(board[rowOld-1][colOld+1]==1) {
                        qDebug("IN +1 -1 moving over another");
                        board[row][col]=2;
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld][colOld]=0;
                        board[rowOld-1][colOld+1]=3;
                        repaint();
                        board[rowOld-1][colOld+1]=0;
                    }
                }
                //qDebug("Set is Moving False");
                isMoving=false;
                indexMoving=0;
            }
        }
        else {
            //qDebug("In the else");
            //repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qt ships with a good IDE, called QtCreator. It has convenient user interface for debuggers. Use it to step through your program and to watch values of variables. This way you will know the exact state of your program in any given moment and you will spot an error in no time.

Comment: Second that - use QT creator's debugger.

Comment: If you're having draw issues look at the part of the logic which draws based on conditions.

Comment: This code has so many rookie mistakes. The code is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). For loops are used in wrong places (where expression should be used, for loop is used, when for loop should be used cor is repeated). `QMainWindow` is abused.